# ToggleButton onTouchListener not working after screen on

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button, lockscreen

I have an PTT App where, if I receive a call and my screen is off, the screen must turn on and the activity bring to the front. This is working, however, if I try to press and hold the ToggleButton in this activity, it'll only listen for the first touch, and act as the ACTION_UP event never happens. This is how the ptt onTouchListener is implemented:

```
pushToTalkButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && activeCall == null) {
                    initiateCall();
                }else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && activeCall != null) {
                    endCall();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: is it possible that activeCall is null?

Comment: No. I placed breakpoints inside onTouch. With the normal behaviour it is getting called lots of times, to check the current state. After the change (Screen off -> on), it only gets called once, at the first touch.